# How can I counter Tryndamere?

Tags: league-of-legends

Welcome to League of Legends question of injustice, featuring Tryndamere, the bosses favorite.

Recently, and more than once, the random team I was playing with got owned by a less skilled, opposing team, specifically because they had Tryndamere...

My problem is that when *my team had no stun* and Tryndamere seemed unstoppable on late game, he even started the fight(along only 3 companions), killed 2 and left spinning, alive.

How do you counter that?

Comment: You can always play draft instead of blind bick. Then ban him. :D

Comment: I well-timed ignite during Tryn's ult will spell his doom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tryndamere is one of League of Legend's melee carry-s, which means, indeed, that he becomes nigh-unstoppable lategame as he gets more and more items (though despite what you may think, Tryndamere is not nearly as powerful *now* as he was back near release)

Tryndamere's counter is hard CC. If you don't have CC (which is quite possible in blind pick), you have no real option other than to prevent him from getting kills in the first place.

This is, in part, why Tryndamere is considered something of a "newbie stomper" - without CC and coordination, both often lacking in newer players, he can be a royal pain to deal with.

The truth of the matter is that Tryndamere, like all carry-s, is fragile. **Without his ult**, he melts like paper, especially under focus.

What Tryndamere wants you to do, more than anything else, is stand still and let him crit you to death. So don't let him - use your CC to snare him, slow him, keep him at arms length. (I dare say you'd be hard pressed to find a team of 5 without *one* slow or better betwixt all of them)

The goal when fighting Tryndamere should be to get him to use his ult, then disable him for its duration, then kill him. If he uses his ult to flee, all the better - re-engage on a team fight within 2 minutes, and it'll still be on cooldown, making him prime to focus.

In terms of surviving Tryndamere, you want armor, and lots of it. A Thornmail will cause Tryndamere's massive crits to likewise sliver his own health, while a Frozen Heart will reduce his attack speed while providing you armor (and mana).

Comment: For point of reference: back near release, Bloodlust stacks gave Tryndamere increased Critical % damage (instead of crit chance), and his passive gave him increased attack speed. This meant that as soon as Trynd activated his ult and reached 1 health, he started swinging near the attack speed cap with 300% damage crits. Stack crit, activate ult, pentakill. Today's Trynd is **much** less insane.

Comment: Thanks for the great reference! My situation was kinda revolting, since I'm not a total noob (+150W), and my team had some nice teamplay. And we did had 2 decent slows, but no snare or stun :/

Comment: Indeed, after he had his ult cast he was easy to kill, myself playing Rammus killed him with a exaust while he didn't realize the thorn damage.. Its just that in all battles, they were less numbered, less skilled, still took his advantage and won, hard to press back!

Answer (score 5):

I take him down with Malzahar with no problems, ultimate combo + ignite can kill him even if he has ultimate.

Malazhar is a strong mid champion (can play lane too) that has a powerful combination: you silence your enemy with the Q; then you put the null zone (W) and malefic Visions (E), and you suppress your enemy with your ultimate on top of the null zone. You will deal a lot of unavoidable damage in a second; he can eventually lunch his ultimate if you don't kill him, but at that point, you throw malefic visions again, and ignite! Usually I kill him this way ;)

Comment: Hi, PifMeister, and welcome to the site. Would you care to expand your answer a little more, about *why* this works for you?

Comment: Hey, PifMeister, I'm going to go ahead and edit your comment into the body of your answer. It's great info, so don't keep it under the comment! In the future, you can do this yourself with the "edit" button. :)

Comment: I will, this was still my first post, and I posted it with my iPhone, so I couldn't do a lot about it. I hope to learn a lot here!

Answer (score 1):

Tryndamere has one of the strongest late games in League of Legends. However his early game is weak, and he is very susceptible to early game pressure through Jungle Ganks and Harass in lane. When picking to counter Tryndamere select a champion with strong early game presence to deny him early farm and delay his late game.

Comment: Most Tryndameres will go solo top to get a high CS, having some kind of ranged atack (like jayce or yoric) is great agaist him because you can zone tryn very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to just ban trynd, but you do not always get to make that decision.  Just make sure you bring some hard cc, and a couple exhausts.  It is important to not just stand there and let trynd hit you, auto attack then move while your auto attack resets.

Comment: Tryndamere is just soooo easy to counter kitt/exaust/ignite him he will die. Ban him is just such an error :-D Take Mordekaiser ult him and ignite after 3 sec ult you will get a super ghost ^^

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find counters to use webistes wiht most updated data about balance, f.x. about tryndamere look on this page: http://www.picklol.net/tryndamere and look on score for each good counter and try to think why people vote for those counters?

teemo - mushrooms that help escape if tryndamere under ulti, speed and poison that allow to haras tryndamere all the time.
rammu - armor and stun that make tryndamere's ulti not useful at all.
etc